# Modify date time to a specific format

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm having trouble coding a conversion to a specific time format along with converting to string format.  I have the following code.

```
  txtMonday->Text = Convert::ToString(dtpMondayIn->Value);
```

I want txtMonday(text box) not only to display dtpMondayIn's value(datetimepicker), but in h.mm format.  Currently, it will display the date and time, for example, January 1, 2014 8:40:30 AM.  I want the text box to show only 8.40 as in hours and minutes.  How could I code this?  I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and c++ language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure but

try this,

```
txtMonday->Text = Convert::ToString(dtpMondayIn->Value.ToString("hh:mm tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

OR

```
Convert::ToString(dtpMondayIn->Value.ToString("hh:mm",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Also check [DATETIME PICKER VALUE PROP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

and [DATETIME FORMATS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Let me know in case it works.